# Auto width for floated div

Tags: css, html, css-float

here is my code

```
<div class='content'>
  <div class='div1'>content</div>
  <div class='div2'>content</div>
</div>
```

```css
.content { width:300px;}
.div1 { float:left;width:200px;}
.div2 { float:left;width:100px;}
```

in some case I need to set `display:none` for `div2`. is it possible to set `.div1` width to full-size of `.content` ( 300px )

Comment: When you set `display:none` on `div2` why not set `width:auto` or `width:100%` to `div1` at the same time? (and maybe `float:none`)

Comment: @jmbertucci , .div2 generated on run-time . I'm looking for css-based solution .

Comment: Are you adding a class that sets the display: none, or are you adding display: none inline?

Comment: what language do you use? how is div2 generated? because like jmbertucci said, it would be easiest to add a class or any style to div1 at the same time...

Comment: I'm using MVC 3 , and put `.div2` as section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reorder your divs, and use `overflow: hidden`:

```
<div class='content'>
  <div class='div2'>content 2</div>
  <div class='div1'>content 1</div>
</div>
```

```css
.content { width:300px; overflow: hidden;}
.div1 { overflow: hidden;}
.div2 { float:left; width:100px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

So long as you only need to add or remove the second div, the easiest solution is to only make that second div a float, and place it within the first, non-floated div, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Tb89A/ .

Just remove the comments on the display:none to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add class (for example, `hidden`) to `div2` when you set `display: none` and then set `fullwidth` do `div1` (in which you define `width: 300px`). Finally, you can go with jQuery and conditionals:

```
if($('.hidden').length()) {
   $('.div1').addClass('fullwidth');
}
```

Of course you may want to change those class names to more specific ones.

I can't think of any different solution, since CSS doesn't allow conditional statements.

Comment: so there is no solution with css ?

Comment: Like I said, CSS itself doesn't support conditional statements. So might want to stick with jQuery (or do it in pure JS). One more option is, if you maintain those divs on the server side, you can write conditional statement in PHP.

Comment: I would use Tomek's addClass method. It's good practice to setup styles in css and actions in js